# No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement

Tags: swift, firebase

I recently copied a project over from an old project on Xcode. I keep getting the following message when I try to build/run the app. The old project compiles fine, but the new project doesn't look the same as the old one. I'm new to Swift, btw.

> [I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement

Comment: That's a pretty vague question and going to be hard to answer; we don't know how you 'copied' the project; copy and paste the code? Made a copy in the finder? Something else? It appears that there was an SDK included in your prior project that was not 'copied' to thew new one and/or perhaps the podfile is different. We're going to need more info to really help.

Comment: Recently encountered this exact error from the Firebase/Analytics package in Flutter. @stackinMyPaper - Did you ever resolve this error in Xcode?

Comment: Did you find the problem? I experience the same issue right now.

Answer (score 2):

It should be something related to Firebase/Analytics